# Saving strings into an easily accessible file format (e.g XML)

Tags: java, javafx

I’m very new to coding, but have recently been designing a sign in/out system for the reception at my place of work.

I’m using Java/JavaFX on version 12.

I’ve done the UI design, and have parsed/stored all the required input data into strings from my button event, but I’m struggling to understand how I can now export these strings into a file.

My initial thought was XML as then the receptionists could open that file in excel and just see who’s signed in/out, but the countless googling has all lead to articles that I’m struggling to understand.

I’m basically after something I can place into my submit button event which then writes it to the file, which I will then mirror over the network to the receptionist PC for viewing.

If anyone can point me into the right direction of how I can achieve this I’d really appreciate it! Im happy to provide any code if it helps, but everything I have at the minute works, I just need to know how to save these darn strings!

Comment: If you want it to open in Excel then save it as .csv file

Comment: Saving `String`? You can write them to a file. Writing to a file, you can use pure string or some format like `JSON`.  You can also use a database like `SQLite`.

Comment: I agree with @Jure. Look into Apache CSV.

Comment: There are multiple libraries for writing data to text files of different formats. (json, xml, csv, ...) I wouldn't recommend relying on file updates for communication though.Some programs (e.g. Excel) try to impose some kind of lock on a file to avoid concurrent modifications.E.g. Excel creates a hidden file when opening a file and deletes it on closing it.Also concurrent access to the file could cause serious issues.I recommend setting up a server instead.If you use the right kind of server,you don't even need to write a seperate app for employees: They could simply do the input via web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also store them in a CSV file which contains multiples entries. `Username` or `Password` would be some of them (`login date` maybe?).

For this use can use such libraries as [openCSV](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv) who work great with JavaFX/Java

Also think of at least hashing the password with [md5 algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/java-md5)

All the backend processings should be done in a sort of [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to avoid occuping the main JavaFX Thread

Comment: Thanks Hassam, openCSV is serving nicely!